# keep spring form select value

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-mvc

I use Spring MVC 4 bring a list and show on the website

```
<s:select path="almacenesByAlmOri.codAlm" id="select1" name="select1" onchange="tr_EnviarAlmacen('select1');" items="${listalmacen}" itemValue="codAlm" itemLabel="nomAlm" class="form-control input-sm"></s:select>


<script>
function tr_EnviarAlmacen(sel){
  var cbox = document.getElementById(sel);
  var valor = cbox.options[cbox.selectedIndex].value;
  var red = "getprodxalm?cod_alm="+valor;
  location.href = red;
}                                                
</script>
```

As I can keep the option of a select spring form selected by reloading the page?

Answer (score 0):

View is rendered by server everytime you refresh(I mean the 'hard refresh' without browser caching) the page, that means Model is refreshed and proper selected values are injected in to the view(the values wich were posted and saved).

To keep selected option while you refresh your page you have to use AJAX.
You need to HTTP POST selected options everytime user selects something in your select form.